Kafka rebalance across instances and threads
So I tried to find an answer for this question but couldn't find one.
Suppose I have 2 instances of an application with 2 consumer threads in each
(total of 4 consumers), all with the same consumer group, and the topic has 2 partitions,
Is it likely for Kafka to assign the 2 partitions to 2 consumers from the same instance?
In other words, does Kafka try to even out the consumer threads between instances?
I asked ChatGPT and it said it doesn't, but I tried to find a concrete answer to this question.

So I looked at consumer logs from our production environment, which is configured for 4 instances with 6 consumer each (24 total) with only 12 partitions on the topic and it seems to be balanced across the 4 instances with each using exactly 3. I don't think we have a special configuration in place.

